# Get the url of an image saved in SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have been using the SharePoint List for quite some time now. But now I am facing an issue. I have entered three columns in a SharePoint List and uses the information in the SharePoint List to display it on the site. I want to display the image by using the URL entered from the SharePoint List.
[SharePoint List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwKUT.png)

I am using this js code for making the image to be displayed on-screen.

```
/**The function for displaying the data received from the list**/
function displayList1Details(data){
$.each(data.d.results, function(key, value){
console.log(value);
$("#thoughts").append(value.Thoughts),
$("#thoughtsName").append(value.EmployeeName),
$("#thoughtsImage").attr("src", "value.PictureLink") });
}
```

I am not able to display it and I have tried it with "value.PictureLink" and without quotes. Still not working. Can anyone tell me a solution for this? Or is it not possible?

The console when logged shows like this
[Console log part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfCjr.png)
[console log part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWWFQ.png)

Comment: If you paste your code directly into the question instead of an image you might get an answer faster. You can use markdown ticks ```like this``` to format it nicely too!

Comment: After this line: `$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {` Add: `console.log(value);` and post the results from the console window.

Comment: Thanks for your help! much appreciated.

Comment: This is console window result.

Comment: @binsonjimmy I do not see where you posted the console window result.

Comment: init.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: How can I add an image? here

Comment: I am not sure how to add picture here. You can edit your question and add the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove quotes from `value.PictureLink`.

Sometimes in SharePoint, SharePoint will do additional work to "sanitize" your input to avoid script execution.

You can see from the output of the console.log, the value of `value.PictureLink` = `<div class="..."><p>http&#58;//updaters.sharepoint.com/sites/spdev/SiteAssets/pics/myImage.jpg<br></p></div>`

I assume the type of the column is `multiple lines of text`. Change this to `single line of text` and then try your code. If this does not work, please post an updated Console Log picture.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. You were right! the column shouldn't be "multiple lines of text". I created a new column with the "single line of text" and copied the link into it. It worked well. Thanks Again!!!